# pthread_create not working. passing argument 3 warning

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, pthreads

I am trying to create a thread and from what I remember this should be the right way to do it:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5

int SharedVariable =0;
void SimpleThread(int which)
{
    int num,val;
    for(num=0; num<20; num++){
        if(random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
            usleep(10);
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("*** thread %d sees value %d\n", which, val);
        SharedVariable = val+1;
    }
    val=SharedVariable;
    printf("Thread %d sees final value %d\n", which, val);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t< NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, SimpleThread, (void* )t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

And the error that I'm getting is this one:

> test.c: In function ‘main’: test.c:28: warning: passing argument 3 of
>   ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type
>   /usr/include/pthread.h:227: note: expected ‘void * (**)(void **)’ but
>   argument is of type ‘void (*)(int)’

I cannot change the SimpleThread function so changing the type of the parameter is not an option even though I already tried and it didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`SimpleThread` should be declared as

```
void* SimpleThread(void *args) {
}
```

When you pass parameters to your thread, it is best to define a `struct` for them, pass a pointer to that `struct` as `void*`, and cast back to the right type inside the function.

Comment: I tried doing that but then I get errors every time I use the int which

Comment: @fgualda87 As a quick one-timer you can pass `int` as `void*` -- just to make sure that your code works. Add `int which = (int)args;`, and the code should compile and run. You should consider wrapping that `int` in a `struct`, though.

Comment: Perfect it worked! Is there any way to do this without changing the SimpleThread method?

Comment: @fgualda87 Unfortunately, no: the "signature" of the method (i.e. its return type and the types of its parameters) are locked by the pthread library.

Comment: Just change your `pthread_create` to call a proxy function (`SimpleThreadProxy`) that, in turn, calls `SimpleThread` with the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a compiling and "working" version of your program, although I have to admit to not knowing exactly what it's doing.  For the critics in the audience, I apologize in advance for the `pthread_join` loop at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 5

struct my_thread_info {
    long which;
};

int SharedVariable = 0;

void *SimpleThread(void *data)
{
    int num, val;
    struct my_thread_info *info = data;

    for (num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
        if (random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
            usleep(10);
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("*** thread %ld sees value %d\n", info->which, val);
        SharedVariable = val + 1;
    }

    val = SharedVariable;
    printf("Thread %ld sees final value %d\n", info->which, val);

    free(info);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    struct my_thread_info *info;
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);

        info = malloc(sizeof(struct my_thread_info));
        info->which = t;

        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, SimpleThread, info);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Strangely, yes. I'll add it though.

Comment: No, this changes my SimpleThread method too much. Thanks though!