# Producer Consumer problem: Incompatible pointer type C

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads, producer-consumer

The code returns the following output. I saw a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253025/pthread-create-not-working-passing-argument-3-warning) before but the solve there was

```
void* funcname(void *args) {
}
```

I applied that and yet I am still facing this issue. I tried what i know so far and am only ending up with a part of the output. I am confused as to what is causing the issue.

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:33:42: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   33 |         pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, producer, &thread_id[i]);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~
      |                                          |
      |                                          void * (*)(int *)
In file included from main.c:2:
/usr/include/pthread.h:200:15: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(int *)’
  200 |       void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:36:42: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   36 |         pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, consumer, &thread_id[i]);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~
      |                                          |
      |                                          void * (*)(int *)
In file included from main.c:2:
/usr/include/pthread.h:200:15: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(int *)’
  200 |       void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:30:5: warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 7 bytes into a region of size 6 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   30 |     strcpy(source, "abcdef");
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 is produced abcdef in buffer
1 is consuming  from buffer
0 is consuming  from buffer
```

I was attempting the Producer Consumer Issue. This is my approach to the problem using mutex, sephamore and pthreads. My entire code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10
#define BUFLEN 6
#define NUMTHREAD 2

void* consumer(int *id);
void* producer(int *id);

char buffer[BUFLEN];
char source[BUFLEN];
int pCount = 0;
int cCount = 0;
int buflen;

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t nonEmpty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t full = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int thread_id[NUMTHREAD] = {0, 1};
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t thread[NUMTHREAD];
    strcpy(source, "abcdef");
    buflen = strlen(source);
    for (i = 0; i < NUMTHREAD; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, producer, &thread_id[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUMTHREAD; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, consumer, &thread_id[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUMTHREAD; i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void *producer(int *id)
{
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    while (pCount == MAX)
    {
        printf("Producer %d is waiting for empty buffer\n", *id);
        pthread_cond_wait(&nonEmpty, &count_mutex);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < BUFLEN; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = source[i];
    }
    pCount++;
    printf("%d is produced %s in buffer\n", *id, source);
    pthread_cond_signal(&full);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
}

void *consumer(int *id)
{
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    while (cCount == MAX)
    {
        printf("Consumer %d is waiting for full buffer\n", *id);
        pthread_cond_wait(&full, &count_mutex);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < BUFLEN; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = '\0';
    }
    cCount++;
    printf("%d is consuming %s from buffer\n", *id, buffer);
    pthread_cond_signal(&nonEmpty);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
}
```

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. It expects producer() and consumer() to take a void * argument, but your versions take an int * argument.

Comment: replace `void *consumer(int *id) {` with `void *consumer(void *p) { int *id = p;`

Comment: @tstanisl answer seems right. The problem is that it is mandatory that the prototype passed to pthread_create has a void * which you can cast later as he said